# Running NPM subprocess results in "Cannot find module"

Tags: python, node.js, windows, subprocess

I'm creating a python script that should run my backend and frontend using `npm run start` as both are node projects.
The subprocess should not wait until they finish to execute the next line of code, I would like to detach them.

I'm developing on Windows 10.

When doing so I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\CodigoAsisa\Backend\npm'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
```

I'm using the following code:

```
subprocess.Popen(["node", "npm", "run", "start"], cwd="C:\\CodigoAsisa\\Backend",
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       universal_newlines=True)
```

I've tried also the following code:

```
subprocess.run('cd C:\\CodigoAsisa\\Frontend && npm run start',shell=True)
```

When using the above (the one using `subprocess.run()`) code I get no errors related to node (nor errors whatsoever), but this doesn't allow me to detach my process, thus continuing to the next line of code.
I need this process to run in the background, and, as far as I can tell, subprocess.run() waits for the process to end.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using `where npm` which returned my executable location, in this case located at C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
Subsequently changing my code to:

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm.cmd", "run","start"],cwd="C:\\CodigoAsisa\\Frontend",
                           stdout=devnull,
                           universal_newlines=True)
```